# Ehcache class configuration and query cache for the same class has any advantages

Tags: spring, caching, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

Any performance advantage if we configure Ehcache for a class and query cache for the same class

```
<cache name="com.model.Employee"
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="100" overflowToDisk="false" statistics="true" />

<cache name="employees" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" overflowToDisk="false"
 timeToLiveSeconds="60" statistics="true" />
```

Is that first configuration is really needed if we do query cache

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"), @QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value="employees")})
    List<Employee> findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

The entity cache and the query cache are two very distinct things.

The entity cache caches entities, so Hibernate can look up entities by Id in the cache without going to the database.

The query cache on the other hand caches results of queries. So for a given query, it stores the result (I assume basically Ids) of that query. So with these Ids it then can consult the entity cache to obtain entities.

From the description above it should be obvious that: yes it makes perfectly sense to use both.